# How can i return list of min value in dataframe in r?

Tags: r

Example: I have a data frame as below:

```
| Date                 |  value |
| 1/2/2020             | 1      |
| 1/3/2020             | 2      |
| 1/4/2020             | 3      |
| 1/5/2020             | 1      |
| 1/6/2020             | 1      |
| 1/7/2020             | 3      |
```

The result should be:

```
| 1/2/2020             | 1      |
| 1/5/2020             | 1      |
| 1/6/2020             | 1      |
```

I had tried

```
df[which.min(df$value),]
```

but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: when you say it didn't work, is there any error.  if you want to return all the rows where the min values are, use `==` i.e. `df[df$value == min(df$value),]`.  `which.min` only returns the index of the first occurrence of minimum value

Comment: "when you say it didn't work, is there any error" -> no, it returns just 1 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which.min` only returns the index of first minimum value

```
which.min(c(5, 1, 3, 1, 2))
[1] 2
```

Instead, create a logical vector with `==` on the `min` value

```
df[df$value == min(df$value, na.rm = TRUE),]
```

Or use `%in%` which would be safe even when there are `NA` values (return FALSE where NA are found whereas `==` returns `NA`)

```
df[df$value %in% min(df$value, na.rm = TRUE),]
```